# Code works fine in CodeBlocks, but I get a RE when I upload it to Google Kickstart competition

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm trying to solve the first problem "Wiggle Walk" of Google KickStart Round C 2019. You can find more information here:
https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050ff2/0000000000150aac
I've tried some test input and everything seems to work fine. However when I submit my attempt I get a Runtime Error. Any idea of why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T, N, R, C, Sr, Sc;
    string str;
    cin >> T;
    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
        cin >> N >> R >> C >> Sr >> Sc;
        cin >> str;
        Sr -= 1;
        Sc -= 1;
        int a[R][C];
        for (int j = 1; j <= R; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= C; k++) {
                a[j-1][k-1] = 0;
            }
        }
        a[Sr][Sc] = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
            if (str.at(j-1) == 'E') {
                while (a[Sr][Sc+1] == 1) {
                    Sc += 1;
                }
                Sc += 1;
                a[Sr][Sc] = 1;
            }
            else if (str.at(j-1) == 'W') {
                while (a[Sr][Sc-1] == 1) {
                    Sc -= 1;
                }
                Sc -= 1;
                a[Sr][Sc] = 1;
            }
            else if (str.at(j-1) == 'S') {
                while (a[Sr+1][Sc] == 1) {
                    Sr += 1;
                }
                Sr += 1;
                a[Sr][Sc] = 1;
            }
            else if (str.at(j-1) == 'N') {
                while (a[Sr-1][Sc] == 1) {
                    Sr -= 1;
                }
                Sr -= 1;
                a[Sr][Sc] = 1;
            }
        }
        cout << "Case #" << i << ": " << Sr+1 << " " << Sc+1;
        if (i != T) {
            cout << "" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[R][C];` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: What should I put instead?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.  That's the dynamic array class for C++.  Second, your code will fail to compile for compilers such as Visual C++, all due to that array declaration.  In addition, maybe that runtime error is caused by the array you've declared blowing out the stack memory. Yet another reason to use vector.

Comment: If you take a look at the limits set for R and C in the question, the max is 10000.  So imagine a 2d array of 10000 x 10000 integers.  That would easily blow out the stack.  A vector gets the memory from the heap,  not stack, thus would be able to handle such memory requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I was able to solve both test sets with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T, N, R, C, SR, SC;
    string str;
    cin >> T;
    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
        cin >> N >> R >> C >> SR >> SC;
        cin >> str;
        SR -= 1;
        SC -= 1;
        vector<vector<bool> > a(R, vector<bool>(C));
        a[SR][SC] = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
            if (str.at(j-1) == 'E') {
                while (a[SR][SC+1] == 1) {
                    SC += 1;
                }
                SC += 1;
                a[SR][SC] = 1;
            }
            else if (str.at(j-1) == 'W') {
                while (a[SR][SC-1] == 1) {
                    SC -= 1;
                }
                SC -= 1;
                a[SR][SC] = 1;
            }
            else if (str.at(j-1) == 'S') {
                while (a[SR+1][SC] == 1) {
                    SR += 1;
                }
                SR += 1;
                a[SR][SC] = 1;
            }
            else if (str.at(j-1) == 'N') {
                while (a[SR-1][SC] == 1) {
                    SR -= 1;
                }
                SR -= 1;
                a[SR][SC] = 1;
            }
        }
        cout << "Case #" << i << ": " << SR+1 << " " << SC+1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but with the 2021 round C "Alien Generator" challenge (also I code in C):

https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000435c44/00000000007ec1cb

Solution works in the code blocks, but not in the kickstart enviroment (causes a runtime error).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    long T;
    long G;
    long x;
    long y;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(x=1; x<=T; x++){
        scanf("%d",&G);
        y=1;
        for(long k=1; k<G/2.0; k++){
            if(pow(2*k-1,2) + 8*G > 0 ){
                double d = sqrt(pow(2*k-1,2)+8*G);
                if(d==floor(d) && (1-2*k+d)>0 && (1-2*k+(long)d)%2==0){
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", x, y);
    }
    return 1;
}
```